# Ошибка в php уже голову сломал

Tags: php

всем привет
вот в этом листинге:

```
<?
function registrationCorrect()
 {
    if ($_POST['login'] == "") return false; //не пусто ли поле логина  
    if ($_POST['password'] == "") return false; //не пусто ли поле пароля
    if ($_POST['password2'] == "") return false; //не пусто ли поле подтверждения пароля
    if ($_POST['mail'] == "") return false; //не пусто ли поле e-mail
    if ($_POST['lic'] != "ok") return false; //приняты ли правила
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(\w|[.]|-|_)+([a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9])([a-z0-9.-]*)([a-z0-9])([.]{1})([a-z]{2,4})$/is', $_POST['mail'])) return false; //соответствует ли поле e-mail регулярному выражению
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])(\w|-|_)+([a-z0-9])$/is', $_POST['login'])) return false; // соответствует ли логин регулярному выражению
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) return false; //не меньше ли 5 символов длина пароля
    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) return false; //равен ли пароль его подтверждению
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_1 WHERE login=$login");
    if (@mysql_num_rows($rez) != 0) return false; // проверка на существование в БД такого же логина
    return true; //если выполнение функции дошло до этого места, возвращаем true }
    ?>
```

такая вот ошибка:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in
>   Y:\home\ty.ty\www\registration\lib\function_global.php on line 18"

Понять не могу никак где я и что пропустил?

Comment: а кто тело функции закрывать будет? что скобочка в комменте делает? бегом ее оттуда

Comment: @BOPOH он то его закрыт, только она попала под комментарий))) `возвращаем true }`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, так я и говорю - что там скобочка делает? ей не там место + автору по коду: проверки `isset(...)` не хватает, начинать надо как `<?php`, закрывающий `?>` вообще не нужен, `mysql_*` устарело, `...WHERE login=$login"` привыкать так писать запросы не надо + из-за `$_POST` как тестировать? Лучше передавать это через параметры (т.е. хотя бы как `registrationCorrect($_POST)`), а в теле функции уже с какой-то переменной работать. И сейчас как ошибку понять, если что-то валидацию не прошло? Т.е. код стоило бы переписать

Comment: @BOPOH скорее всего он учится по урокам, и скорее всего старым, я когда то по таким же учился, до того как появился даже тот же `PDO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя не закрыто тело функции. Закрывающая скобка попала под комментарий в предпоследней строке.

> return true; //если выполнение функции дошло до этого места, возвращаем true **}**

Вынеси его за комментарий, и все заработает

Comment: блин как я не заметил xD спасибо

Comment: @qazqaz закрывай вопрос, если ответ тебе помог